# Between function in spark using java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have two dataframe :

```
 Dataframe 1
+-----------------+-----------------+
|    hour_Entre   |   hour_Sortie   |
+-----------------+-----------------+
|      18:30:00   |     05:00:00    |
|                 |                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
 Dataframe 2
+-----------------+
|  hour_Tracking  |            
+-----------------+
|  19:30:00       |
+-----------------+
```

I want to take the hour_tracking that are between hour_Entre and hour_Sortie.

I tried the following code :

```
boolean checked = true;
 try{
         if(df1.select(col("heureSortie")) != null && df1.select(col("heureEntre")) !=null){
           checked = checked && df2.select(col("dateTracking_hour_minute").between(df1.select(col("heureSortie")),df1.select(col("heureEntre"))));
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But I get this error :

```
Operator && cannot be applied to boolean , 'org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>'
```

Comment: The error message is correct, it makes no sense to && a boolean and a Dataset. What are you trying to achieve here and why? What should that code produce if there is more than a single row in both tables? What is the purpose of `checked`?

Comment: I want if the between function returns true the value of cheched becomes true

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for hour difference -

**1st create date difference**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('date_diff', F.datediff(F.to_date(df.hour_Entre), F.to_date(df.hour_Sortie)))
```

**Then calculate hour difference out of that -**

```
df = df.withColumn('hours_diff', (df.date_diff*24) + 
                          F.hour(df.hour_Entre) - F.hour(df.hour_Sortie))
```